# Rectangle Method C++

Tags: c++, integral

I copied an example project from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangle_method), but I don't understand part of it: `(i - 0.5)`.    Why is `(i - 0.5)` being computed?

```
double rectangle_integrate(double a, double b, int subintervals, double (*function)(double))
{
   double result;
   double interval;
   int i;

   interval=(b-a)/subintervals;
   result=0;

   for(i=1;i<=subintervals;i++){
      result+=function(a+interval*(i-0.5));
   }
   result*=interval;

   return result;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It represents the middle of the interval. When i is 1 the interval is 0 to 1, and 0.5 is the middle of it. Etc.